# Circuitikz buffer port has not "up" anchor

Tags: circuitikz

I was trying to create a circuit that uses a buffer that "doubles" the output (one is negated, the other is not). In essence, something like this:

[image]

but with horizontal up and bottom connections.

Page 142 of the manual has a great example on how to do this:

[image]

The problem is that, even when using the latest version (corresponding to the latest manual version, 1.4.4), I cannot use this circuit as the `up` anchor doesn't seem to exist for the `buffer port`.

Is this a bug in the latest version(s)? What can I do to achieve this?

Here's a MWE:

```tex
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[emptypmoscircle]{circuitikzgit}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0) node[and port](A){A} (A.out)
node[buffer port, anchor=in,
component text=left](B){B} (B.bin)
node[schmitt symbol, above left]{}
(A.bin 1) node[schmitt symbol, right]{};
\node [notcirc, left] at (A.bin 1) {};
\node [notcirc, above](C) at (B.up) {};
\draw (C.north) |- ++(-1,1) (B.down) --++(0,-1);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Notice that you need the latest version of circuitikzgit for this to work, available [here](https://circuitikz.github.io/circuitikz/).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like you need `ieeestd buffer port`.

Comment: Looks like you are just right! Thought the IEEE style was the default one, my bad.
Thanks!

Comment: @Z.Alessandro I'd like to have IEEE style as default, but it would break a lot of old circuits... sizes are really different. So it's an opt-in...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the start of the section (4.21.6 "IEEE logic gates usage."), there's a notice

> The rest of this section will assume you have issued the command `\ctikzset{logic ports=ieee}`, so that the short form of the names is used.

Which applies to that particular example in the manual.

If you don't include that command, you need to use the long form `ieeestd buffer port`.